# Is it a good approach to use different compiler and module combination between project build process and unit tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, tsc, ts-node

New to the typescript. I'm trying to use mocha framework to add unit tests to one our nodeJS/typescript projects.

Our typescript application uses `tsc` compiler with `esnext` module.

I couldn't able to make Mocha to use `esnext` module to run the tests (it works fine with commonjs module). Seems like ts-node doesn't detect the imports with esnext module, but it has no issues when used with `commonjs` module.

- So, I'm wondering **is it a good practice to use different compiler and module combination between project build process and unit tests?** i.e. tsc and esnext for build process and ts-node and commonjs for unit test.
- Are there any potential issues/risks we might face in future if we proceed with this approach?
- Is there any way to make Mocha to use `tsc with esnext` or `ts-node with commonjs` or `ts-node with esnext`?
- Or Am I missing something conceptually with the way typescript or Mocha work?